# How can i allow the user to edit individual fields in a table using a form

Tags: php, sql, loops, if-statement

I have a table of pupil data (including name and class).

When editing that data using a form, the user can edit both the name and class and it updates the database. When the user just updates the name it updates the database. But when the user tries to just update the class it erases the field in the database.

For the pupil the input type is text, whereas the class uses a dropdown list which is populated with class names from the database.

When the user hits submit, the following code:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

            if(isset($_POST[updatename])){
                $update = "UPDATE pupil SET pupil_name='$_POST[updatename]' WHERE pupil_id = $_POST[id]";
                mysql_query($update) or die(mysql_error());
            }
```

//THIS CURRENTLY WIPES THE DB FIELD
        if(isset($_POST[updateclass])){
            $updateclass = "UPDATE pupil SET `class_id`='$_POST[updateclass]' WHERE pupil_id = $_POST[id]";
            mysql_query($updateclass) or die(mysql_error());                
        }


        session_start();
        $new = "'$_POST[updatename]' has been updated!";
        $_SESSION['new'] = $new;            
        header("Location: pupil.php");
        exit();
    }

I think it's something to do with the if loop because when both are set the update is successful! All help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can we have the html code too? It seems your PHP is right.

Just tips : Force you to concatenate vars =>
`$new = $_POST['updatename'] . "has been updated!";`

It may be few, but with some more things your PHP could be perfect.

Comment: the entire form doesn't fit in the comment capacity.

It's so strange that all is updated when both are set, class name works when only set, but when class name not set wipes the DB field!

Comment: I would see the HTML but try to get the road of your code :
- You submit your form with different vars
- Vars come in your PHP
- In your PHP you put a if
- updatename exists? change it
- updateclass exists? change it
- put 'updatename has been updated' in session

You enter in your IF all the time and maybe you lose vars meanwhile